# Unable to install EntityFramework 6.1.3 in VS2015 web project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In my VS2015 WebApi project, I try to install NuGet package EntityFramework 6.1.3 using the following command from Package Manager. The command runs with success as the message below shows. But the package is still not installed and I get an error when I compile the project:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
Installing NuGet package EntityFramework.6.1.3.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' to myWebProjectName
```

**The compile error**:
Error   NU1001  The dependency EntityFramework >= 6.1.3 could not be resolved. myWebProjectName C:...\WebAPI\ProductService\src\ProductService\project.json

**Here is my project.json file**:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData": "5.7.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

The Reference folder in the project is empty and there are no NuGet packages installed as shown in the project screenshots below:

[image]

Solution Explorer Window:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

After I closed the project and re-opened it, the Reference folder is showing two folders DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core5.0 with some error icons as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36749421/6523054). Basically apparently there is something called EntitityFrameworkCore now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you used the ASP.NET 5 template to create your Web API project.

Right click on your references folder, in your project, and click "Restore Packages".  Then rebuild.

I don't think Entity Framework 6 is supported for DNX Core. So you might have to remove that reference as well.  Right-click on "EntityFramwork" under DNX Core 5.0 and click Uninstall Package.

Do you see the DNX stuff like in this image?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm using ASP.NET 5 Web API template. After restoring packages(per your instructions), when I rebuild the project, I get the error: `The dependency Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.6.0 in project myWebProjectName does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0`

Comment: That error is probably true.  Meaning, EF6 might not be supported in DNXCore.  If you can rely on DNX 4.5.1, then I'd just uninstall that package from underneath DNXCore as well.  Which is weird, because I don't think Edm gets installed by default or with EF.

Comment: I've added screenshots of my project along with an `UPDATE` section . There is no package installed.

Comment: After I closed the project and re-opened it, I'm seeing the DNX stuff as shown in my new `UPDATE 2` section above.

Comment: The tooling is a bit behind.  You need to wait and see what comes in VS Update 2 (or go install the RC).

Comment: @DougWilson We've VS2015 Enterprise Edition RC1 - Update 1

Comment: @nam VS2015 update 1 is real RTM (no RC).  But Update 2 is in RC. I'm surprised you have VS2015 RC.

Comment: @SteveKennedy I was able to remove EntityFramwork" under DNX Core 5.0 but it removed it from under the folder DNX 4.5.1 as well. How can I keep EF under DNX 4.5.1?

Comment: @nam The best thing might be to remove 5.0 completely. I don't think EF6 is supported at all there.  You can remove 5.0 by opening up the project.json file and removing it from the frameworks node.  The other thing you could do, if you're brave, is try EF7-RC.  I think it supports both frameworks.  Let me know if this answer/thread helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Entity FrameWork `"EntityFramework": "6.1.3"`, by
`"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"`,
It Work Properly then bulid it.  Also see the screeshot i added.

[image]