# ASP.NET 5 Web API project template does not allow using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Using VS2015 Enterprise Edition, I created a web app using `ASP.NET 5 Web API` template as shown below. But when I try to install Entity Framework, it shows the EntityFramework under the `References\DNX Core 5.0` folder (as shown in [figure 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35950206/1232087)) with an error icon stating the DNX Core 5.0 does not support EF. But when I uninstall EF from this folder, it removes it from the `References\DNX 4.5.1` folder, as well.
**Question**: How can I use EF in an ASP.NET 5 Web API project?

**project.json file**:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: What version of EF are you installing? And do you want to target the full .NET Framework, or .NET Core or both?

Comment: @mason I am installing EF 6.1.3. I need EF only for [this tutorial](http://blog.medhat.ca/2015/10/odata-v4-endpoint-using-aspnet-web-api.html) but I want to use `ASP.NET 5 Web API` template instead.

Comment: share your `project.json` please

Comment: EF 6 doesn't run on .NET Core. That's what EF 7 is for. So either don't build for .NET Core or switch to EF 7.

Comment: @aguafrommars Per your request, I've just added `project.json` file code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF 6 is not compatible with `.Net core`. Either, remove `"dnxcore50": { }` from your supported framework in your `project.json`
For more information using `EF 6` with `ASP.NET Core` visit : [Getting Started with ASP.NET 5 and Entity Framework 6](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html?highlight=entity)

Or use `EF 7` : Visit [Getting Started on ASP.NET 5](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/getting-started.html)

Comment: Per your suggestion, I removed `"dnxcore50": { }` from project.json and was able to use EF6.