# .NET Core 1.0 and EntityFramework 7 Not Compatible

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I've upgraded to Visual Studio Code 1.0.0 and I'm trying to retrofit an ASP.NET Core project I was working on in VSCode previously, before the new release. VSCode is seemingly quite different now in terms of configuration. I've worked with [this tutorial](http://www.tattoocoder.com/setting-up-asp-net-core-debugging-in-vs-code/) and [these samples](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples). I'm having reasonable success getting the MVC6 aspect of my project compiling and working properly, but the EntityFramework 7 aspect is a no-go.

When I do a `dotnet restore` on my project, I get the following error:

```
Package EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0).
```

I've been experimenting more-or-less randomly with the project.json in the hopes of finding a solution, but I don't seem to be making much progress. Is netcoreapp1.0 still just too new to be retro-compatible with EntityFramework? What options are available?

Here's my project.json, by the way. It's pretty much stock from the HelloMvcApi sample mentioned above, but with the addition of the EntityFramework.Core dependency:

```
{
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-*"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "imports": "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in [this announcement of breaking changes in RC2](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144) :

> The **EntityFramework.*** packages and namespaces are changing to  **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.***

So you'll just need to switch your reference to point to the updated version :

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
```

Comment: Progress for sure. But now `dotnet restore` yeilds: `Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0` and `Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0`. I know those are related to the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` dependency because I ran a quick trial. Any idea about these new errors are or they for a separate question?

Comment: OK, I've accepted this answer. Technically, I still have an unanswered, although associated question (as mentioned in the comment immediately above). I figured I'd post it over on Github. The link is **[here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5152)**. Thanks also to @Pinpoint, but technically this answer appeared sooner and was a bit more complete.